# ¿Cómo creo un programa en C que almacene los nombres de 5 animales y se imprima la dirección de memoria cuando el usuario elija alguno de ellos?

Tags: array, c, punteros

//El siguiente programa obtiene la dirección de memoria de uno de los 5 nombres de animales introducidos por el usuario. Esto es lo que llevo, solo que necesito que el programa pida un solo nombre de un animal para que de su dirección de memoria//

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   const char* x[5]={"León","Tigre","Jaguar","Chita","Puma"}; //Queda claro que &x[0]es 
   equivalente aX. Y, x[0]es equivalente a *x.
   int i; //Básicamente, &x[i]es equivalente a x+iy x[i]es equivalente a *(x+i).
   int *p;
   

      printf("Escribe el nombre de un animal: "); 
      for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      
      printf("Dirección de memoria del valor:[%d] = %p\n", i, x[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ya te habían contestado parte de la pregunta, no te estamos haciendo la tarea no?

Comment: No, para nada busco que me hagan la tarea, si te fijas aunque el código es similar basado en su ayuda le estoy preguntando otra cosa. Por su comprensión gracias.

Comment: @Michel pero no es lo mismo que me preguntaste en los comentarios?

Comment: En efecto Mateo, pero como no vi ninguna respuesta asumí que tenía que replantear mi pregunta, pero bueno, consultaré en otro lado, gracias.